# SQLAlchemy relationship with task_instance table in airflow

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm using airflow and I want to be able to track all files generated by given task instances in a table `airflow.file_list`, which is part of the same database used by airflow (running on postgres). Using SQLAlchemy I have the following mapper for my `file_list` table:

```
from airflow.models import Base

class MySourceFile(Base):
    """ SQLAlchemy mapper class for the file_list table entries."""
    __table__ = Table('file_list', Base.metadata,
        Column('UID', Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('task_id', String(_ID_LEN), nullable=False),
        Column('dag_id', String(_ID_LEN), nullable=False),
        Column('execution_date', DateTime, nullable=False),
        Column('file_path', String(_ID_LEN), nullable=False),
        Column('file_sha256', String(_ID_LEN), nullable=False),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['task_id', 'dag_id', 'execution_date'],
            ['task_instance.task_id', 'task_instance.dag_id', 'task_instance.execution_date']
        ),
        extend_existing=True,
    )

    instance_task = relationship(
    TaskInstance,
    primaryjoin=and_(
        TaskInstance.task_id == __table__.c.task_id,
        TaskInstance.dag_id == __table__.c.dag_id,
        TaskInstance.execution_date == __table__.c.execution_date
    ),
    viewonly=True,
    foreign_keys=[__table__.c.task_id, __table__.c.dag_id, __table__.c.execution_date]
)
```

I'm importing the declarative base from `airflow.modles` because I've read that it's necessary for interacting mappers to share the same instance of base. In the above codes-snippet I want `instance_task` to reference the task_instance that created the file. The table columns `task_id`, `dag_id` and `execution_date` in my table `airflow.file_list` mirror the primary keys in `airflow.task_instance`. Unfortunately, when I run the airflow server, I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|MySourceFile|file_list'. Original exception was: Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'MySourceFile.instance_task' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables
```

I'd prefer not to modify the airflow source if possible. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but installing airflow and using your model all is good. I'd make sure that the table in use really ends up having the fk constraint. You're using `extend_existing`, so you should be covered even if the table exists in metadata prior to this definition and without the fk, but do double check.

Answer (score 0):

First off specifying `__table__` like that is odd (I've never seen it before), and as a general rule anything starting with and underscore is private and should be avoided.

You need to specify that `task_id` is a foreign key. Something like this:

```
task_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('task.id'))
```

The [docs on SQL Alchemy relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) are useful if you haven't seem them. And the [`backref`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) pattern might be useful to create a relationship from task instance down to your custom file without having to alter the TaskInstance model.

Comment: Specifying the columns/table in the way I've done is referred to as [Hybrid Approach](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#using-a-hybrid-approach-with-table) in the documentation. I had previously used the declarative approach you suggest but with no success.

Comment: Ah right. Still, you should be able to pass `ForeignKey(task_instance.id)` to the Column() call in this mode.

Comment: Oh. I missed entirely that it was a composite foreign key.